# want to delete line number which is not process from file in python and append unprocess data at the end of file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I want to process data from file **'post_data.txt'** if data not get processed then i want to delete those line number if not then i want to append dose data in file.
without using another file.

*To run the code delete_and_update_file():*

```
def write_fail_operation(data):
    with open('post_data.txt', 'a') as datafile:
        datafile.write(data+'\n')

def file_update(data):
    try:
       """
       this block for operation on data
       data: is string
       """
    except:
        write_fail_operation(data)

def delete_and_update_file():
    post_data_file = 'post_data.txt'
    line_num_list = []
    with open(post_data_file, 'r') as datafile:
        for line_no, line_data in enumerate(datafile.readlines()):
        file_update(line_data)
        line_num_list.append(line_no+1)
    with open(post_data_file, 'r+') as datafile:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(datafile.readlines()):
            if line_no in line_num_list:
                datafile.writeline('')
```

Comment: And your question/problem is ...?

Comment: it is not working as expected.
i want to delete line from the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
def delete_and_update_file():
    post_data_file = 'post_data.txt'
    except_line_nos = [] # line numbers with exceptions
    with open(post_data_file, 'r') as datafile:
        # read file into a list
        lines = [line.strip() for line in datafile.readlines()]
    # loop to process each line and append each except_line_no
    for line_no, line_data in enumerate(lines):
        try:
            """
            this block for operation on data
            line_data: is string
            """
        except:
            except_line_nos.append(line_no)
    # reverse the order and prepare for pop operation
    except_line_nos.reverse()
    # delete and save all except lines to a list
    bad_lines = [lines.pop(i) for i in except_line_nos]
    # if you care about the sequence to append, then reverse it
    bad_lines.reverse()
    # append the except lines back to lines list
    [lines.append(bad_line) for bad_line in bad_lines]
    # save back to file
    with open(post_data_file, 'r+') as datafile:
        datafile.write('\n'.join(lines))


delete_and_update_file()
```